# Customização do eixo X no matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, data.frame, matplotlib

Bom dia,
tenho o codigo:`import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
server250_mar19 = pd.read_csv('dbnode2_mar19.csv')
plt.plot(server250_mar19.Date, server250_mar19.CPU_pct)
plt.show()`

o meu ficheiro csv contem os seguintes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando tento visualizar o grafico obetenho o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que poderá estar errado? Peço uma dica.

Fernando

Answer (score -1):

Ao que parece você está montando o eixo X na coluna de data, porém boa parte das suas datas são iguais o que muda é a sua coluna de tempo. Os dados estão fora de ordem, ordene os dados por data e hora, logo depois monte novamente o gráfico que o mesmo deve organizar.

```
server250_mar19.sort_values(['Date', 'Time'])
```

Uma dica as Labels do eixo X estão sobrepostas rotaciona elas 45 graus que ficará legível:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Caso necessite de mais ajuda comente na resposta, estou a disposição.